# Is there a way to import an RSS feed into Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, rss

I have a SharePoint site that has a list that I would like to get into Excel for status reporting.

Can I do this via the RSS feed?

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking on my Sharepoint site for some information about importing RSS feed from WSS to Excel but I can't figure it out.

But! I've fond that site that you can read and maybe, I hope, will give you some hints or info that you are looking for: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointtechnology/HA100214251033.aspx

Also, maybe this site can usefull: http://mindsharpblogs.com/penny/archive/2007/06/15/1888.aspx

Hope this will help!

David.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a much easier way, depending on what you are really trying to accomplish. Excel is actually capable of reading a WSS/MOSS list.

- Open your the SharePoint List you want to analyze in Excel (http://server/Lists/MyList/AllItems.aspx)
- On the Actions menu for that list, choose Export to Spreadsheet